# WordPress images are not displayed correctly in responsive it gets fixed height and width

Tags: php, wordpress, image, responsive, srcset

I am in the process of building a new site using wordpress 4.6.1. Out of the box it supports responsive images.
I have created a new theme and have simply added the loop to display the post content.
When I insert an image into a post it displays the image correctly but it isn't responsive i.e. it does not serve a different image dependant on the browser size.

The image HTML generated is as follows:

```
`<img
width="1110"
height="740"
src="http://digitaltestsite2.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Feature-Story-1110x740.jpg"
class="attachment-large size-large wp-post-image"
alt="Feature Story"
srcset="
    /wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Feature-Story-1110x740.jpg 1110w,
    /wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Feature-Story-600x400.jpg 600w,
    /wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Feature-Story-768x512.jpg 768w,
    /wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Feature-Story-250x167.jpg 250w,
    /wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Feature-Story-500x333.jpg 500w,
    /wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Feature-Story-350x233.jpg 350w,
    /wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Feature-Story-700x466.jpg 700w,
    /wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Feature-Story.jpg 1200w
"
sizes="
    (min-width:1199px) 1110px,
    (min-width:991px) 768px,
    (min-width:767px) 590px,
    (min-width:543px) 500px,
    295px
"
```

> `

(N.B. I have added a filter for the sizes attribute to enable more breakpoints.)

**If I remove the width and height the image is responsive but wordpress seems to be generating this so I dont believe I should have to remove it.
I have tried and replicated this in both Chrome and Firefox.**

Does anyone have any suggestions as to whether this is the correct behaviour and/or if I am doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: how you are getting images from wordpress ? have you used get_post_thumbnail function for that ?

Comment: I'm simply inserting them using the post editor, insert media.

Answer (score 1):

Testing this stuff can be tricky. For one, once Chrome (and I think Firefox and Safari, too) have a resource that is *larger* than they need in the cache, they will not load smaller ones over the network. For two, `sizes` can be fiendishly complex to mentally model...

Fixing it by removing `width` and `height` makes no sense, as I believe the parsed `sizes` size trumps the `width` when it comes time to determine layout width, and which resource to load out of the `srcset`.

I suggest:

1. Try clearing your cache between tests
2. Even if that solves it... whenever you're doing anything with responsive images feeding your page into https://ausi.github.io/respimagelint/ is always a good idea!

Comment: I've tried clearing the cache but still the set width and height seems to take precedence. I will give the tool you suggested a go. Thanks

Comment: So I ran on of my pages through the lint tool and the response was as follows:  **The sizes attribute has to match the width of the image**

The size of the image doesn’t match the sizes attribute (min-width: 1199px) 1110px, (min-width: 991px) 768px, (min-width: 767px) 590px, (min-width: 543px) 500px, 295px. At a viewport of 1000x563 the image was 1110 pixels wide instead of the specified 768 (45% difference). The affected viewports are 300x169-1180x1573.

Comment: **The strange thing is If I remove the width and height values for the image, the image works perfectly and resizes as required.**

Comment: So after testing this, you're right! The `height` and `width` attributes override `sizes` to set the display width, when there is no CSS.

Comment: `srcset` and `sizes` are about *loading an image to match the layout width*. But it's still best practice to set an explicit layout width in CSS -- in your case, if you want to keep the height and width attributes, it should be `img { width: 100%; height: auto; }` (you could also use `max-width`, if you never want your resources to be upscaled)

Comment: The test case is here http://ericportis.com/etc/stackoverflow_example_2016-11-08.html Removing both the CSS *and* the height/width gets scaling to `sizes` widths... removing just the css locks it at a width of 1110... whenever there is CSS it determines the display width. You should still heed the linter's call and try to match your sizes widths to the actual display width, once you get that working.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this @Eric - the problem for me is that wordpress is generating the height and width when I insert the image which seems odd because as you have said it overwrites the srcset and sizes. It must be something I'm not seeing as I can't understand why wordpress would do that.